# I can't write # in React Native Linking

Tags: react-native

I want to write a call, similar to this image
[image: I need this characters]

But

```
Linking.openURL('tel:${*#*#4636#*#}')
```

Only writes `*` and can not write `#`.

What should I change such that it writes `#` as well as `*`?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using special characters, you should first encode the phone number using eg. [`urlencode`](https://github.com/node-modules/urlencode) like so:

```
import encode from 'urlencode';

Linking.openURL(`tel:${encode('*#*#4636#*#')}`)
```

This will modify the string to *%23*%234636%23*%23, which the phone app should be able to accept.